# How to make a toggle dark theme using Angular ( Not Material )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, rxjs

**I wanted to make a toggle dark theme for my project which will work in every component**

the resources i found was on angular material. but i dont wanna use that,

is there any way to do it?

please help!

Comment: There is no theming built into Angular. You'll need to build it.

Comment: hey @HereticMonkey how can i build it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, you are getting me wrong. i meant, can you tell me the steps/techniques that how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, on your toggle button add a click functionality and change properties and accordingly change colors too. Something like this:

```
// In your HTML

<div [class.dark-class]="isDark" [class.white-class]="!isDark">

   <button (click)="isDark = !isDark">Toggle background</button>

</div>



// In your SCSS file, have 2 class, one called dark-class and the other white-class

.dark-class { background: black }
.white-class { backgrond: white }


// In your component.ts file, add a boolean value 'isDark' and set it to false initially 
private isDark: boolean = false;
```

So here what happened is, initially since the boolean value is dark, the div will have a 'white-class' background since i added a '!isDark' condition on the [class.white-class] and when you click the button, i am changing 'isDark' to '!isDark' which means, the 'isDark' will now become true and then the background changes to a dark color.

This is one approach where you can follow.

Comment: thank you so much brother!!!!!!! but i have a question! when i use private in the .ts file.
it throws an error.

and the question is how is this applicable for globally in every component?

Comment: You need not use private...you can simply define isDark: boolean = false;

Answer (score 0):

For your other question: How to do this globally? you can do something like this:

```
// If you have a service which is being used across all the components, you can use it otherwise create a new one like this: 

1) Create a file and name it a commonService

// Inside common service: 

@Injectable({ provideIn: 'root' }) 

export class CommonService {
  globalIsDark: boolean = false;

  setGlobalDark(value: boolean) {
    this.globalIsDark = value;
  }

  getGlobalDark(): boolean {
    return this.globalIsDark;
  }
}


// Now in your styles.scss file, add the dark and white classes
.dark-class { background: black }
.white-class { backgrond: white }


// In every component, wherever you want to use, do this: 


constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}

isComponentBGDark: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  // If you want to use what's there, do this
  this.isComponentBGDark = this.commonService.getGlobalDark();

  // If you want to set the theme to dark, do this: 
  this.commonService.setGlobalDark(true);
}
 
// In your component HTML
<div [class.dark-class]="isComponentBGDark" 
     [class.white-class]="!isComponentBGDark"
>

</div>
```